# The strategy must take into account the fact that the signal must be triggered if the closed candle is without a wick

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssDgK.png)

On this picture, is applied my strategy, I would like to add a condition to it:

The signal should be triggered only if the closed candle is without a descending wick (in the case of a bullish signal).

Can you help me ?

Comment: How can a new candle be not __wickless__? On your picture we see candles that are closed, not new.
A new candle starts when the first price of that time frame arrives. It will be a single data. Single data candles cannot have wicks. This will be the Open price. When the next data arrives and it is not the same as the Open, that will be either the Low or the High. And this will be the first wick.
Your can rephrase the request to `the signal must be triggered on a new candle if the previous closed candle is without a downward wick`

Comment: Yes sorry, I corrected my request

Answer (score 0):

I would test a wickless candle like this

`NoWickCandle = math.min(open, close) == low and math.max(open, close) == high`

Comment: This is good for __closed__ candles. Not for real-time candles (which is a new candle will be).

Comment: the close value in real-time refers to the current candle value, not necessarily the close final value.
See what I mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.The **close** value of a real-time candle will very rarely be "necessarily the close final value" as it might change every tick.Thus, as **close** changes, the only way it is always equal to **low** (or **high**) if price moves only in one direction,like it only grows,which is very unlikely. **close** price will probably fluctuate, creating new highs/lows.As a result,the indicator will repaint a lot. That is why I wrote it is good for closed candles,where the OHLC is determined. Of course it is good, if you don't mind your condition flipflop from TRUE to FALSE a lot.